# Typing function components with names

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The new way of declaring React function components with TypeScript appears to be (option 1):

```
interface IProps {
  bar: string;
}

const Foo: React.FC<IProps> = ({ bar }) => <div>{bar}</div>;

export default Foo;
```

However that uses an anonymous arrow function, which some people believe makes debugging more difficult.

Option 2 would be:

```
export default function Foo({ bar }: IProps): JSX.Element {
  return <div>{bar}</div>;
}
```

Option 3 is very verbose, but does include the "official" type:

```
function InternalFoo({ bar }: IProps): JSX.Element {
  return <div>{bar}</div>;
}

const Foo: React.FC<IProps> = InternalFoo;

export default Foo;
```

There may be other options as well.

What is the idiomatic / preferred option and why?

Comment: Other than the TS definition, all 3 of these are completely equivalent, I don't see how debugging would be any worse / better in either one.

Comment: @James I thought `function` set the display name on React components but anonymous arrow functions did not.

Comment: ah ok, in that respect of naming then yeah you'd get that for free with other components - but you can assign names to anonymous func components e.g. `MyFunc.displayName = 'MyFunc'` so I still don't see it as a huge issue.